# Interpretation of well-ordering theorem

Tags: general-topology

According to Munkres' book topology, the Well-ordering theorem is given as:

> If $A$ is a set, there exists an order relation on $A$ that is a well-ordering.

Then, Munkres writes that this theorem allows us to index any set $A$ with the elements of some well-ordered set $J$. But, I do not see why this is so.

Doesn't the Theorem just give the existence of a well-ordering relation, say $C$ on $A$?

How do I show from the existence of $C$ that there exists a set $J$ and  bijection, say $f$ such that $A$ is indexed by $J$?

Comment: Well, if $A$ can be well-ordered, then it can just be indexed by itself, no?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is itself well-ordered, then setting $J = A$, the identity is an indexing $J \to A$. I think the point of this notational separation is that the set $A$ may have another standard ordering. For example, if you well order the reals, it may be less awkward to talk about a bijection $J \to \mathbb{R}$ for well-ordered $J$. One can then talk about the (well) ordering on $J$ and the (standard) ordering on $\mathbb{R}$ unambiguously; without the $J$ notation, when one talks about the ordering on $\mathbb{R}$, one must specify whether this is the standard ordering or the well-ordering.